# Context in a Dockerfile with ShellScript

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a Dockerfile via ShellScript, but the `docker build` doesn't work.

My directory hierarchy is (in `/home/deploy`):

```
shellscript.sh
platform-backend
  watcher
     container
        Dockerfile
```

In my shellscript I want to execute this line:

```
docker build -t vmelo/watcher -f ./platform-backend/watcher/container/Dockerfile .
```

So, I want to build the image `./platform-backend/watcher/container/Dockerfile` but I want that my image context as the root directory `/home/deploy`(folder that contains platform-backend and shellscript.sh) because there are others files in this root folder that the Dockerfile must use.

The problem is, if I execute this command in the shellcript.sh or I execute in the terminal that is in pwd `/home/deploy`, nothing happens. There is no error message, it just waiting forever.
I tried to change the command to

```
docker build -t vmelo/watcher -f ./platform-backend/watcher/container/Dockerfile ./platform-backend/watcher/container
```

And that command works, but it's not what I want because I want my context in `/home/deploy`, not `./platform-backend/watcher/container/Dockerfile`

I am in a docker Ubuntu machine 18.04

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your home directory.

`docker build -t vmelo/watcher -f ./platform-backend/watcher/container/Dockerfile .`

I tried similar example in my Windows Machine were I was able to access file from root project folder and my Dockerfile was buried in deep.

The example I tried is

`docker build -t sample:v1 -f ./build/docker/Dockerfile .`

And I had copy with different folder path in my docker file.. like this,

`COPY ./build/docker/application.war ./src/main/docker/docker-entrypoint.sh ./`

The reason your may be hug or stuck because you are running in your home directory `~` which have other folders and file (os and User related), which may not be a idle place to run it. Move it to a different folder under your user folder, which have only your project and try again.